# Form submitting even though it's encased in an if statement, and condition is not met?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, boolean

I've got an entire validation code bound to `$('#post-button').click`. The idea is, the variable `e_exit` is set to `true`, then the data within the form goes through a series of checks. If it meets the condition of any if statement, a message is displayed with the issue, and `e_exit` is set to `false`. Except the problem is, that it isn't done properly, as the form is still submitted (like a quarter of a second after the message is displayed).

I'm dealing with boolean values here, so typecasting certainly can't be the issue, I really don't understand what's going on:

```
$('#post-button').click( function() {
    var e_exit = true;
    var notif_message = '<div class="notification red"><div class="cross"></div>';

    var name = $('input[name=name]').val();
    var url = $('input[name=url]').val();
    var urlrgx = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?/i;
    var urltst = urlrgx.test(url);

    if(name == '' || name == 'Enter a name for this offer') {
        $('#notification').html(notif_message + "You need to enter a name for this offer name. Try to pick something that you'll easily remember when seen again.</div>");
            e_exit = false;
    }

    if(!urltst) {
        $('#notification').html(notif_message + "You need to enter a valid offer url prefixed with http:// for this offer.</div>");
            e_exit = false;
    }

    var rotation_select_val = parseInt($('select[name=r_id]').val());
    if(rotation_select_val != 0) {
        var min_val = isNaN($('input[name=r_min]').val());
        var max_val = isNaN($('input[name=r_max]').val());

        if(min_val || max_val) {
            $('#notification').html(notif_message + "You need to enter a numeric value for your rotation's min and max hits for this offer.</div>");
            e_exit = false;
        }
    }

    var geo_select_val = $('select[name=g_country\\[1\\]]').val();          
    if(geo_select_val != 0) {
        var geo_url_val = $('input[name=g_url\\[1\\]]').val();
        var geo_urltst = urlrgx.test(geo_url_val);

        if(!geo_urltst) {
            $('#notification').html(notif_message + "You need to enter a valid url prefixed with http:// for your geo-location targets.</div>");
            e_exit = false;
        }
    }

    if(e_exit) {
         $('form').submit();   
    }
});
```

Any answers as to why this could be happening, or edits with explanations would be of a great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `#post-button` is a submit button, you need to return `false` to stop form submission.

A better solution would be to bind to the form's `submit` event:

```
$("#your-form").submit(function() {
    // validate...

    return e_exit;
});
```

This will only allow the form to submit if you return `true` from the event handler.

**Edit:**

Perhaps the ajax plugin is also subscribing to the `click` event of the post button? In that case, I'd return false and make sure to stop the event propagating further like so:

```
$("#post-button").click(function(ev) {
    // validation
    ev.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It's not a submit button, and the problem is it's already bound to some ajaxForm plugin (which I now wish I hadn't used), and I simply don't have the time to re-integrate everything and the ajaxForm plugin, I'd rather just understand why if `e_exit` is set to false, it still submits.